# Implementing a Lock Screen widget on the Home Screen - Android?

Tags: android, widget, locking

So, a few users have been asking me if I could make a home screen widget that launches my app..

Due to sensitive content, I've made a simple "Enter the password" splash screen. If the pin is correct the user gets access..

I've been getting complaints that it's a little slow and annoying to enter that every single time.

Majority of the requests I'm getting are relating to accessing the app quickly from the home screen itself. Using the simple shortcut icon is literally the same thing, since it will again open up the password screen..so I need something different.

So I need to open the app from the home screen, using a widget. I need the opening process to be say under 3 seconds or so... and I need to confirm the identity of the user.

What I'm thinking is a Lock Screen, or Pin screen widget.

Is there a way to replicate the Android Lock Screen inside a widget ? ... Remember, I need it on the home screen...
I think a 3X3 grid widget should do....
But there's absolutely no mention anywhere on how to do this... Is it possible? If so, how?

I want exact same functionality, the user can say, set a lock screen combination inside the app, disable the pin entering splash screen, put up the widget - and open the app from there.

Again, there's no mention anywhere of anything relating to this.

So, Any ideas on where I can get more help? Or how I might go about accomplishing this ?